# CICFlowMeter Command Line Interaction

Tags: java, linux, gradle, gradlew

I have come across a problem where I have to use CICFlowMeter for Educational Purposes but the problem is that I cannot automate the process using CICFlowMeter Graphical User Interface (GUI) which is the default way to interact with this app based on its [Github page description](https://github.com/CanadianInstituteForCybersecurity/CICFlowMeter).
I have to run

```
sudo gradle execute
```

every time I want to use this app!
Is there any easier way to use this app using the command line in Linux?
How can I automate the process of converting .pcap files into .csv files as the CICFLowMeter output in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

run "gradlew build",then "gradlew distZip",you can get zip in "build/distributions/".you can use command "cfm [input_file_name] [output_directory]" to execute.(i just try it in windows)